# Calling function with 2 parameters on matrix of dimension n x 2

Tags: matlab

I have a function f that takes two parameters and want to apply the function on each row of a matrix M with dimension n x 2.

I have tried using, num2cell(M, 2) and then calling cellfun(@f, num2cell(M,2)). This doesn't work since f takes two arguments and not a vector.

But then calling cellfun(@f, num2cell(num2cell(M,2)(1))) resulted in the error:

```
error: binary operator '^' not implemented for 'cell' by 'scalar' operations
```

f looks as follows:

```
function y = f (r, phi)
  y = r^(2/3)*sin(2*phi/3);
endfunction
```

Can someone tell me how to call the function on the matrix, where each row vector is automatically split into 2 scalars?

Comment: Any reason not to manually pass `M(:,1)` and `M(:,2)` separately like this? Cells should probably work as something like `C = num2cell(M,2); f(C{:})` give or take a transpose.

Comment: Oh, and you need to vectorize your function by using `.^` and `.*` inside.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: But only convert to cells if you really need to: they're slow. Since you don't have any votes or answers yet, consider deleting your question as it unlikely to be helpful for future readers :)

Comment: There goes my statement regarding answers... deletion would now be problematic.

Comment: uh, sorry, didn't see it. Deleted it

Comment: Thanks @Leander, you da real MVP ;)